# How to start a Python ipython shell, automatically run inside it a few commands, and leave it open?

Tags: python, bash, shell, ipython

I tried

```
echo "print 'hello'" | ipython
```

Which runs the command but ipython immediately exits afterwards.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit:**
I actually need to pass the command into the interactive Django shell, e.g.:

```
echo "print 'hello'" | python manage.py shell
```

so the -i switch gimel suggested doesn't seem to work (the shell still exits after execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ipy_user_conf.py inside your ~/.ipython

Answer (score 5):

Use the same flag used by the standard interpreter, [`-i`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i).

> `-i`
>
> When a script is passed as first argument or the -c option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command, even when sys.stdin does not appear to be a terminal. The PYTHONSTARTUP file is not read.

A Linux example, using the [`-c` command line flag](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/reference.html#command-line-usage):

```
$ ipython -i -c 'print "hello, ipython!"'
hello, ipython!

In [2]: print "right here"
right here

In [3]:
```

Comment: well, I cheated a bit, my actual python command is already "python manage.py shell", for starting the interactive Django shell. So I can't see how the -i solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of ipython but the basic python interpreter has a command line parameter to give you the prompt after it executes the file you've given it. I don't have an interpreter handy to tell you what it is but you can get it using `python --help`. It should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Running a [custom startup script/profile script with the Django shell was marked as closed: wontfix](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6682).

However, there is a shell_plus Django extension discussed in that ticket which seems to do what you want. I haven't had a chance to check it out, but it looks like at the very least it can run a load to auto import all the models of all installed apps (which I usu. find myself doing).

- [Shell plus.py in django-command-extensions on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/source/browse/trunk/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py?r=135)
- [django-command-extensions homepage on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/)
- [django_extensions on Github](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/tree/master/django_extensions/)